# Problems comparing different dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries :

```
dict1=[{'code':'fgx23','number':23},{'code':'dx22a','number':2},{'code':'dsw23','number':10}]

dict2=[{'code':'dx22a','number':9},{'code':'dsw23','number':1},{'code':'fgx23','number':20}]
```

The question is: how to add the numbers that have the same code

For example, in "dict1" the code "dx22a" has the number 2 and the "dict2" the code " dx22a " is number 9 , so the result is 11 .

help and thanks

Comment: what do you do with numbers that don't have matches? and what is the assumed output? another list of dictionaries dict3?

Comment: make a new dict, loop each list of dict, making the code value as the new dict's key and number as it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1=[{'code':'fgx23','number':23},{'code':'dx22a','number':2},{'code':'dsw23','number':10}]
dict2=[{'code':'dx22a','number':9},{'code':'dsw23','number':1},{'code':'fgx23','number':20}]
consolidated = {i['code']:i['number'] for i in dict1}
for i in dict2:
    if i['code'] in consolidated:
        consolidated[i['code']] += i['number']
    else:
        consolidated[i['code']] = i['number']
print(consolidated)
```

Comment: This outputs a dict, the question was working with list of dictionaries.

Comment: And performing a `sum` outputs a number, while the input was a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1=[{'code':'fgx23','number':23},{'code':'dx22a','number':2},{'code':'dsw23','number':10}]
dict2=[{'code':'dx22a','number':9},{'code':'dsw23','number':1},{'code':'fgx23','number':20}]
dict3 = []
for key, value in [(i['code'], i['number']) for i in dict1]:
    for value2 in ([q['number'] for q in dict2 if q['code'] == key]):
        dict3.append({'code': key,'number': value + value2})
print (dict3)
```

This assumes that you only want dict3 to have keys that appear in both dict1 and dict2. Also that your intended output is the same format as dict1 and dict2 (a list of dictionaries). In addition that there is only one of each code in dict1 and dict2